# Best way to serialize Django-nonrel + MongoDb queries for exchanging with mobile devices?

Tags: api, mongodb, web-applications, django-nonrel, bson

I want to exchange information between Django-nonrel+MongoDB and mobile devices via http.  When a mobile device makes a request to the api, the Django view executes a query, and I would like to respond with a serialization of the query results.

My problem is that [Django's built-in serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/) formats don't play well with models containing embedded aggregates and lists.  I could work around that by not using these no-sql features, but that would nullify my motivation for using MongoDB in the first place.

**What is the best way to serialize data from a MongoDB query?**

I know that I can import bson and use the "encode" and "decode" functions, but those only seem to work on dictionaries.  My current inelegant view test code makes a cumbersome embedded dictionary structure from the underlying model:

```
def get_announcements(request):
  """
  Return a BSON representation of the ten most recent announcements relevant to the
  user.
  """
  user = User.objects.get(username='*<somebody>*') # Test User for now
  campaign_announcements = Campaign.objects.filter(workers=user.id)[:10]
  data = {}
  for campaign in campaign_announcements:
    data[campaign.name] = []
    for announcement in campaign.announcements:
      data[campaign.name].append({
          'tagline': announcement.tagline,
          'content': announcement.content,
          'release_time': announcement.release_time,
        })
  return HttpResponse(BSON.encode(data))
```

I would like to be able to do this:

```
return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("bson", <query>))
```

This assumes that bson is the format I ought to use.  I'm assuming this because it's MongoDB's default format.

Responses to other questions mention [PyMongo's json_util submodule](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html).  I looked at it, but I don't think it does what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

UPDATE 20 August 2013:
Thanks to those who responded to my question.  I decided to abandon no-sql.  It seems like an interesting and useful technology, but it doesn't seem to play well with my environment: Django, Heroku, and Android.  Getting embedded objects to serialize in a useful manner seems to take a bunch of hacking that I would rather avoid, and Android uses SQLite, so I would have to convert the serialized data to a schema anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into django-tastypie.  It's got some built in serializers, and it's a REST API for querying based on your Django models.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that!  It will probably be useful to me in the future.  Unfortunately, I don't think it solves my immediate problem.  There's no option for bson serialization, and I expect the other output options to yield the same error messages I get with Django's built-in serialization features.

Comment: I've been using Tastypie, and it's great.  It handles authentication easily.  Thanks again for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at `json_util` as that will translate bson query results to [extended json](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format which you should be able to handle easily in your mobile app.

The alternative is to communicate in bson and handle the decoding to and from binary in your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found to use:

```
.to_json()
```

on the query.

Maybe useful for future lurkers on this question, like me.